# Proof of the Lyapunov Matrix Equation

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions, adaptive-control

Assuming that $A^TP+PA = -Q$ holds, I want to prove that $P = e^{A^Tt} P e^{A^Tt} + \int_{0}^{t} e^{A^T\tau} Q e^{A^T\tau}$ is a solution. After doing the substitutions, I end up with:
$A^TP+PA = A^T (e^{A^Tt} P e^{A^Tt}) A - Q$. What is the reason why the term $A^T (e^{A^Tt} P e^{A^Tt}) A$ becomes zero?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The explicit solution is $P = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{A^T\tau} Q e^{A^T\tau}d\tau$.

Comment: Sorry, the second exponential is not transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the expression $L(P):=A^TP+PA$ where $A$ is Hurwitz stable and define $P^*=\int_0^\infty e^{A^Ts}Qe^{As}ds$, which is well-defined since $A$ is Hurwitz stable; i.e. $e^{As}\to0$ as $s\to \infty$. So, we are interested in solving for $P$ in $L(P)=-Q$. We will show that $P^*$ is the unique solution. Indeed,

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
L(P^*)&=&A^TP^*+P^*A\\
 &=& A^T\int_0^\infty e^{A^Ts}Qe^{As}ds+\int_0^\infty e^{A^Ts}Qe^{As}dsA\\
 &=& \int_0^\infty \left(\dfrac{d}{ds}e^{A^Ts}Qe^{As}\right)ds\\
 &=& 0-Q\\
 &=&-Q
\end{array}
$$
where we have used the fact that $\dfrac{d}{ds}e^{As}=Ae^{As}$. Moreover, if $Q$ is positive (semi)definite, then so is $P$.

The expression $L(P)=-Q$ can be solved for all matrices $Q$ provided that $A$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. This can be seen from the vectorized expression given by $(A^T\oplus A^T)p=-q$ where $p=\mathrm{vec}(P)$, $q=\mathrm{vec}(Q)$, $\mathrm{vec}$ is the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and $\oplus$ is the [Kronecker sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). The eigenvalues of $A^T\oplus A^T$ are the same as those of $A\oplus A$ and are given by $\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_j(A)$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots$, where $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue. So, $A^T\oplus A^T$ is invertible if and only if $A$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Maybe also good to note that the assumption that $A$ is Hurwitz is needed, since then $\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{A\,t}=0$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I have updated the answer.